# CSS: Two Logos aligned to the left and to the right which should autoscale by window resize

Tags: html, css, alignment, scale

I have two logos on my website which should go on top of my website. 
One logo should be aligned to the left and the second logo to the right.
Now when the browser window gets pushed smaller, the space in between those two logos should get narrower and eventually when the two logos "hit" each other, both are supposed to scale smaller without breaking the line.

Right now only the left logo scales down and the right logo breaks the line and gets pushed lower without scaling down at all.

Can anybody help me?

My CSS:

```
.image-wrapper
{
 position: relative;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.scale-image
{
 display: block;
 width: auto;
 max-width: 55%;
 white-space: nowrap;
```

}

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
<a href="#" ><img src="http://www.drogies-test.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Logo_oskar.jpg" align="left" class="scale-image"/></a>
<div />

<div class="image-wrapper">
<a href="#" target="_blank" ><img src="http://www.drogies-test.de/pics/Logo_theater_os.gif" align="right" class="scale-image"/></a>
<div />
```

Example link: http://www.drogies-test.de/header_show.html

Comment: The right logo does scale. I think you just want to set `max-width: 50%` since 2 items of `55%` is more than 100% width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've adjusted the mark-up structure to nest elements correctly.

```css
.image-wrapper:first-of-type,.image-wrapper:nth-child(1) {
    float: left;
}

.image-wrapper:last-of-type,.image-wrapper:nth-child(2) {
    float: right;
}

.image-wrapper {
    max-width: 50%;
}

.scale-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <a href="http://www.drogies-test.de/"><img src="http://www.drogies-test.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Logo_oskar.jpg" align="left" class="scale-image"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <a href="http://www.theater-osnabrueck.de/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.drogies-test.de/pics/Logo_theater_os.gif" align="right" class="scale-image"></a>
   </div>
</body>
```

Here's a `flex` solution:

```css
.image-wrapper {
    max-width: 50%;
}

.scale-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.flex-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <a href="http://www.drogies-test.de/"><img src="http://www.drogies-test.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Logo_oskar.jpg" align="left" class="scale-image"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <a href="http://www.theater-osnabrueck.de/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.drogies-test.de/pics/Logo_theater_os.gif" align="right" class="scale-image"></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note that flex is not supported in legacy browsers like IE 8 and 9, and some older versions of webkit browsers like Safari and Firefox (a deprecated or hybrid syntax variation is supported instead).

**Learn more:** [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Comment: Hello UncaughtTypeError.

thank you so much for your help and your code! This is my first time here so bare with me :)

The logo to the left is scaled down right away when the window is pushed smaller, the right logo scales down much later when keep making the browser window smaller resulting in a too small left logo and the right logo being to big and not on the same line any more. Is it possible that both logos scale at the same time, so the hight of both logos doesn't change? Or that the scaling only starts to come into affect, when logo two touches logo one?

Comment: Happy to help where I can, Superhero360. Welcome to Stackoverflow :)
I would advise keeping those image dimensions the same to begin with, that way it should scale proportionally together as you would expect. So give the smaller logo a larger canvas are so its dimensions match that of the larger logo.
Also, if you feel this answer gave you the solution you were looking for, please feel free to mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Ah thank you for the tip with the image size. I had them on the same height but not the same width. I made both images the exact same size and changed max-width: to 100%. Now it works like a charm. Wonderful!